# Use results of loop for another raster calculation

Tags: arcpy, python, raster, for-loop

I've been looking extensively to find a solution for what I think is a very simple exercise.

In general, I would like to know how I can extract a variable from a loop in Python and then use it elsewhere in the script. I've limited Python knowledge, however I know from `R` that this should be fairly simple. More specifically, my case is explained below.

I've two loops both multiplying rasters. I need to extract variables from each of the loops and then add them together.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "D:/Join"
#
outputFolder = env.workspace
#
# A list of two different rasters
wheat = ["a_wheat", "b_wheat"]
for w in wheat:
    r_w=Times("landuse_w",w) # landuse is a raster
    r_w.save(os.path.join(outputFolder, "r_" + w ))
# This will generate r_a_wheat, r_b_wheat

barl = ["a_barl", "b_barl"]
for b in barl:
    r_b=Times("landuse_b",b)# landuse is a raster
    r_b.save(os.path.join(outputFolder, "r_" + b))
# This will generate r_a_barl, r_b_barl
# 
# Add rasters
add_a = r_a_wheat + r_a_barl
add_b = r_b_wheat + r_b_barl
```

The problem with the loops like this is that I need to save everything and then add up. I would prefer to extract from `r_w` the two rasters (`r_a_wheat, r_b_wheat`), do the same for `r_b` and then add up without having to save files. Is that possible?

Comment: With so few layers to process why go to the effort and add them to a list and cycle through those when you could simply reference them individually?

Comment: I have 10 layers for each loop. I gave this as an example.

Comment: You should always explain the whole situation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have described your problem in a bit more detail, why not cycle through the lists using their index number 0 to 9 pulling out the names, as it appears that you are pairing them.

Pseudo code:

```py
wheat = ["a_wheat", "b_wheat","c_wheat"]
barl = ["a_barl", "b_barl","c_barl"]
for i in range(0,3,1):
    ras1 = wheat[i]
    ras2 = barl[i]
    print "processing " + ras1 + " & " + ras2
    r_w=Times("landuse_w",ras1)
    r_b=Times("landuse_b",ras2)
    add = r_w + r_b
    add.save("yourrastername")
```

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd! I don't want to add all rasters at the end. I need `add_a = r_w_a + r_b_a`; `add_b = r_w_b + r_b_b`; `add_c = r_w_c + r_b_c` That's why I thought of extracting the elements from loops and using them to add at the end.